# Updating or Inserting records into table using informatica

Tags: insert-update, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have two tables ACC and ACC_Restrict. I want to check the values of the column, P_R of either tables to see whether I should either insert, update or do nothing to ACC_Restrict. If the value is active in ACC but not in ACC_Restrict then insert into ACC_Restrict if it is still active in both ACC and ACC_Restrict then do nothing. If it is not active anymore in ACC but is still in ACC_Restrict then update ACC_Restrict by updating end_date to today's date. How can I achieve this in informatica?

Edit: There has been a modification of the requirement. ACC will only contain  modifications to the account of someone. So if nothing has changed in someone's account we don't see anything in ACC but that doesn't mean if he had a restriction before, it has been lifted. It's just because nothing has changed so it doesn't appear in ACC. How do I manage this?

Note: P_R is a restriction on an account. I put the end_date to a date close to infinity and when the restriction is removed from the account I update
ACC_Restrict by changing end_date to present date.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @MarekGrzenkowicz What I did was add ACC and ACC_Restrict as sources to the mapping, filter on both to remove any NULL values. Full outer join where ACC_Restrict is detail and ACC is master. Then I was planning on using udpate Strategy transformation but I wasn't sure what all I was doing was correct.

Comment: I think you are going in the right direction, just use right conditions in update stratrgy for insert and update

Comment: I am having problems with the condition to use in the update strategy. How should I do it?

Comment: Yeah I understand the logic, it is the syntax that is my problem. I have added my mapping

Comment: There's also one more condition: "if it is still active in both ACC and ACC_Restrict then do nothing". This requires a filter after joining. Put a Filter Transformation after Joiner with a condition `not active in ACC or not active in ACC_Restrict`. Also remove existing filters and put a Filter Condition in both Source Qualifiers, this can improve performance.

Comment: @Maciejg Thanks for the tip, I have updated my mapping in the question. What do you think?

Comment: @MarekGrzenkowicz `IIF(isnull(ACC_ID_RES) AND ISNULL(CONTRAT_ID_RES), 'I', IIF(
isnull(ACC_ID_ACC) AND ISNULL(CONTRAT_ID_ACC), 'U'))`. There has been a little change in the requirement. I have updated the question.

Comment: Let's not go to deep into business requirements. What is the **technical** issue that you are facing right now?